# Npm command ignoring flags

Tags: npm

I am using the following command,

```
npm run ng build --watch
```

Running

```
> json@0.0.0 ng C:\Users\json
> ng "build"
```

It ignoring the watch flag, can any one help me on this.

Please don't get into why I am using **`npm run ng build --watch`** that is a big story.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a workaround for this, in package.json added **build:dev** as new command and running **npm run build:dev** solves my issue

```
 "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "build:dev": "ng build --watch"
  },
```